Как применить стили в Angular для корневого элемента
У меня есть компонент у которого такая вёрстка
Этот компонент имеет тег my-header
<img src="{{ path }}" />
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

Я хочу понять как можно прокинуть стили из одного компонента в другой, что именно я хочу:
html: 

...

<my-header />

...


css: 
my-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
}

